# Unable to login to sonar

Tags: mysql, sonarqube, sonarqube5.1

I am trying to setup sonar in my pc.

Following the exact same steps as per official documentation.
I changed the database to mysql and port to 4950.

```
  sonar.web.port=4950
    sonar.jdbc.username=sonar       
    sonar.jdbc.password=root
    sonar.jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sonar?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8&rewriteBatchedStatements=true&useConfigs=maxPerformance
```

Now I can access sonar at port 4950,mysql contains a table of users which has a row of admin but i am unable to login with admin credentials.

I reverted back to its embedded database but still unable to login with admin credentials. Is there any property required to set or am I missing something. Please help

Answer (score 0):

[The docs](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Authorization#Authorization-FAQ) include advice for when `admin` is locked out. In short, you might need to run some SQL:

```
INSERT INTO user_roles(user_id, role) VALUES ((select id from users where login='mylogin'), 'admin');
```